# How to reuse deleted memory entries in MySQL using back

Tags: mysql

I am storing more than 28,000 transaction records in a MySQL table per day. My intention is, after one year, I will move all the records to a summary table and need to delete moved entries from MySQL table and reuse the deleted memory space.

Is there any possible way in MySQL?

Comment: What do you mean by “memory space”? Please explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes . Reuse delete record memory space.I have no idea about that .I am going to try if any possible way.